# How to use WPF as dll in C++ application?

Tags: c++, wpf

I created a C# WPF  GUI and compiled it as a library. I have a c++/cli project. I want to use WPF dll in C++application in order to open the WPF window.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, WPF library cannot be used in C++. Either you have to use WinForms or C++ own windows form as library.
This link can help you but not sure either it will work or not.

[enter link description here](http://www.ronaldrosier.net/Blog/2013/09/26/use_c_class_libraries_in_c_clr_applications)